# java 8 method reference to: either `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`

Tags: java-8, java-stream, method-reference

I tried to convert the body of a method `boolean exists(String value, boolean isCaseSensitive)` :

```
    for(String str : existingNames){
        if(isCaseSensitive ? str.equals(name) : str.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
```

to a solution that utilises java8 method references:

```
    Predicate<String> equalityPred = isCaseSensitive ? 
            name::equals : 
            name::equalsIgnoreCase;

    return existingNames.stream().anyMatch(equalityPred);
```

Then I saw that this way the equality is performed in the opposite direction (e.g. `value.equals(str)` ).
Is there a way to fix this and still use method references, and if no what would be the java8 way.

Comment: what is the issue with having `str.equals(value)` or `value.equals(str)`? Basically, if either of the two is true then the other _must_ also be true.

Comment: @Ousmane Mahy Diaw a possible case might be that the method accepts null values, but the collection will never contain any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no “opposite direction” for equality. The only issue might be the behavior for `null` values. Your loop might fail, if the collection contains `null`, your method references will fail, if `name` is `null`.

You may achieve the original behavior using lambda expressions:

```
boolean check(Collection<String> existingNames, String name, boolean isCaseSensitive) {
    Predicate<String> equalityPred = isCaseSensitive? 
        s -> s.equals(name): 
        s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(name);

    return existingNames.stream().anyMatch(equalityPred);
}
```

but it makes little sense to consider `null` for the `name` parameter, when it will never be equal, as the code will fail with a `NullPointerException`, if the collection contains `null`.

To get a sensible behavior for `null`, you may use

```
boolean check(Collection<String> existingNames, String name, boolean isCaseSensitive) {
    Predicate<String> equalityPred = name==null? Objects::isNull:
        isCaseSensitive? name::equals: name::equalsIgnoreCase;

    return existingNames.stream().anyMatch(equalityPred);
}
```

or just

```
boolean check(Collection<String> existingNames, String name, boolean isCaseSensitive) {
    return name==null || isCaseSensitive?
        existingNames.contains(name):
        existingNames.stream().anyMatch(name::equalsIgnoreCase);
}
```

If you know that the Collection will never contain `null`, but want to support `null` for the `name` parameter, you could also use

```
boolean check(Collection<String> existingNames, String name, boolean isCaseSensitive) {
    return name!=null && existingNames.stream()
        .anyMatch(isCaseSensitive? name::equals: name::equalsIgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well don't use a method reference then and write your lambda directly:

```
     static boolean existsJDK8(List<String> existingNames, String value, boolean isCaseSensitive) {
         Predicate<String> equalityPred = isCaseSensitive ? s -> value.equals(s) : s -> value.equalsIgnoreCase(s);

         Predicate<String> equalityPredReversed = isCaseSensitive ? s -> s.equals(value) : s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(value);

         // return  existingNames.stream().anyMatch(equalityPredReversed);
        return existingNames.stream().anyMatch(equalityPred);
     }
```